# How to groupby one column and get means of other columns

Tags: r

[image]

aggregate(. ~ station, data2017[-14], mean(na.rm=TRUE))
why my command does't work?

Comment: Posting code and data as images makes it really hard for us to reproduce and try to solve your problem. You should post your code, and a [mcve] of your data, as properly formatted text in the body of your question (you can use `dput` to output your data, then paste it in to the question, select it, and click the `{}` button to format it as code).

Comment: Thanks for reminding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to remove the `()` from `mean` or use an anonymous function and then use `function(x) mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)`.  If we don't want to use anonymous function, then specify the parameters and the values for that parameter

```
aggregate(. ~ station, data2017[-14], mean, na.rm = TRUE, na.action = na.pass)
```

NOTE: Here, we may also need the `na.action` as there are NA elements in the columns.  By default, it can remove the NA rows if there is any NA in one of the rows

---

As a reproducible example, we can use the `mtcars` dataset

```
data(mtcars)
mtcars[3:4, 2] <- NA # assigning some NA
mtcars[10, 5] <- NA
aggregate(. ~ gear, mtcars, mean(na.rm = TRUE))
```

> Error in mean.default(na.rm = TRUE) :    argument "x" is missing, with
>   no default

```
aggregate(. ~ gear, mtcars, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
#  gear      mpg      cyl     disp       hp     drat     wt     qsec        vs  am     carb
#1    3 15.72857 7.571429 331.1786 180.8571 3.136429 3.9410 17.56714 0.1428571 0.0 2.785714
#2    4 25.24000 4.600000 120.0600  85.8000 4.075000 2.5640 19.06700 0.8000000 0.7 2.300000
#3    5 21.38000 6.000000 202.4800 195.6000 3.916000 2.6326 15.64000 0.2000000 1.0 4.400000

aggregate(. ~ gear, mtcars, mean, na.rm = TRUE, na.action = na.pass)
#  gear      mpg      cyl     disp       hp     drat       wt   qsec        vs        am     carb
#1    3 16.10667 7.571429 326.3000 176.1333 3.132667 3.892600 17.692 0.2000000 0.0000000 2.666667
#2    4 24.53333 4.727273 123.0167  89.5000 4.054545 2.616667 18.965 0.8333333 0.6666667 2.333333
#3    5 21.38000 6.000000 202.4800 195.6000 3.916000 2.632600 15.640 0.2000000 1.0000000 4.400000
```

Note the difference in `mean` values when we added `na.action`